# handling "Exception in thread.." tkinter, convert in "messagebox.showerror"

Tags: multithreading, exception, tkinter, messagebox

when I get error in target of `thread (t = Thread (target = self._configure_clicked)` it appears on terminal `"Execption in thread Thread-1"` (I have more threads in code).

I want a "messagebox.showerror" to appear if there is an error, and if there is no error "messagebox.showinfo". how can I do this?

I am attaching an extract of the GUI code and the screen of the terminal

```py
from tkinter import * # importo tutto da tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from threading import Thread
import multi_sensor_acc_gyro1 as multi ##other script.py

...
...

def configure_clicked(self):
        
    t=Thread(target=self._configure_clicked, daemon=True)
    t.start()
    ...
    self.pb.start() #progress bar start
    while t.is_alive():
            self.pb.update() #progress bar update
    ...
    messagebox.showinfo("CONFIGURE clicked","the sensors have been configured\n\\n click OK to continue")
    messagebox.showerror("Error","sensor disconnection")
    ...
    ...

def _configure_clicked(self):
    mac_address=["F7:64:55:AD:0A:19","F2:A1:3A:E2:F2:ED","F9:8E:32:DD:1A:EB"]
        
    output_1=multi.configure(mac_address) 
    self.states=output_1[0]
    self.loggers_acc=output_1[1]
    self.loggers_gyro=output_1[2]

...
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyCIb.png)

I tried to use try / except, but I am doing something wrong. I am not detecting any errors:

```
from tkinter import * # importo tutto da tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from threading import Thread
from PIL import Image
import multi_sensor_acc_gyro1 as multi

...
...

def configure_clicked(self):
    try:    
        t=Thread(target=self._configure_clicked, daemon=True)
        t.start()
        ...
        self.pb.start()
        while t.is_alive():
                self.pb.update()
        ...
        messagebox.showinfo("CONFIGURE clicked","the sensors have been configured\n\\n click OK to continue")
        ...
        ...
    except:
        messagebox.showerror("Error","sensor disconnection")

def _configure_clicked(self):
    mac_address=["F7:64:55:AD:0A:19","F2:A1:3A:E2:F2:ED","F9:8E:32:DD:1A:EB"]
        
    output_1=multi.configure(mac_address) 
    self.states=output_1[0]
    self.loggers_acc=output_1[1]
    self.loggers_gyro=output_1[2]

...
...
```

Comment: Use `try` and `except` to catch errros?

Comment: no, I don't use try / except. i don't even care about the type of error, i care if there is any error a messagebox.showerror appears. or a messagebox.showinfo if everything goes well.

Comment: Exactly why I asked you to use `try` and `except` to catch IF any error happens AT ALL.

Comment: I have attached above the try / except modification that I tried to do, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Hmmmm, if an error happens it should trigger the `except` block, are you sure you placed it in the correct line? The error seems to be `output_1=multi.configure(mac_address)` and your `try` is elsewhere

Comment: now it works, I put the try / except in _configure_clicked (). but the error no longer appears on the terminal